# Store edittext into MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a function that store 3 editext values into an object when a button is pressed. These objects are stored into an mutablelist, which will be returned and displayed in a recycleview.

```
    fun getWish(): MutableList<Wish>{
        val wishes : MutableList<Wish> = ArrayList()
        add_button.setOnClickListener {
            val name= name_input.getText().toString()
            val price= price_input.getText().toString()
            val url= url_input.getText().toString()
            val wishTemp = Wish(name, price, url)
            wishes.add(wishTemp)

            print(wishTemp)
            print(wishes)
        }
        return wishes
    }
```

1. The issue is the list is not displaying in the recycleview. The recycle view adapter is not the issue because it was tested with a test list. Is my implementation not working?
2. Print function shows reference values not the actual string. However, the 'wishes' list is added to everytime the button is pressed.

Comment: An `onClickListener` is asynchronous code, the code in the curly brackets (after `setOnClickListener`) gets run later, whenever the view is clicked. Your `getWish` function will always immediately return an empty list.

Comment: Yes thank you! 'getWish()' was returning an empty list.. I needed the 'notifyDataSetChanged()' to update the adapter for each input.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you displaying the new data in the `RecyclerView`? All you're doing here is creating a new list and adding some `Wish` objects to it. You need to add this stuff to your data set in the `Adapter`, and then call one of the `notify*` methods to tell it to update the display (like `notifyDataSetChanged`). You haven't shown where you're doing that, so there's no way for us to know if that implementation is working or not.

(You probably want to show your adapter code anyway, there's a difference between initialising it with some data, and updating it with some other data later)

You're getting references with `print` because, at a guess, `Wish` is a plain class and you haven't overridden the `toString()` method to make it print your strings nicely. If you can make it a *data class* that will give you a default implementation that prints the values of your constructor parameters.

Comment: Apologies for not posting the rest of the code, I figure it might be asking too greedy to have contributors review entire codebase.. You were correct the issue was I didn't implement the notifyDataSetChanged(). That was the only thing. Thank you tons!

Comment: @ottercrossing nah it's cool, thanks for trying not to post too much! But generally it doesn't hurt to post the parts that have some relevance to the thing that isn't working, even if you think they're fine. You have a better chance of someone answering if they have all the info they need, too